# Google Chrome opens about a hundred tabs on startup

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

They are lots and lots of copies of pages that I've pinned before. I've checked my chrome startup settings, and it's currently set to just open the new tab page.

I'm on Mac OS Mavericks.

Comment: I don't think stackoverflow is the place where you should ask this question. Go to Web apps instead. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ There, you might get your answer quickly.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that.

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  @rafaelcosman, did you find a solution?